# VMware ESX/i syslog content

Tags: vmware-esxi, logging, vmware-esx, syslog

I am working on an expansion of our monitoring footprint, and we are currently looking at including data from our visualized environment. As our monitoring license is based on logged volumes, and we are likely to need an increase in infrastructure. As part of this planning we are trying to gauge the value in logging the input, i.e. what information can we get out of the syslog messages.

I have been trying to details of possible syslog messages, however I have been unsuccessful. Is there a complete list of the syslog messages which can potentially appear in logging (even if we have to get this via our support contract)?

Additionally in planning, I have seen it mentioned that the content from two local log files are included in the syslog ouput. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance,

MHibbin

Comment: I would be surprised if what you needed wasn't in `/var/log`...

Comment: What are you interested in logging/capturing? Do you have Virtual Center and a commercial version of VMware?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos, the log files themselves won't be a complete inventory of possible logs message will it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ewwhite, at the moment it is a bit of an unknown but it's to try and gauge what use we can get out of trending the results (i.e. for pro-active monitoring).We have vCenter and do have a paid for license.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @MHibbin, +1 yes, in the future I should probably read before I comment.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos no worries... but yes, that's what I think is strange that Cisco so openly publish their log messages, but no one else will! Thanks